# Laravel model::create function doesn't insert data but doesn't throw any exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Edit: I tested with dd(), it reaches the function and everything runs correctly but doesn't insert the data.

I have a model named ProductCustomer, I can save this model with ProductCustomer::create() function in tests but I can not create it from the service class with the same method. It's not throwing exceptions while trying to save but doesn't insert the data.

My model

```
class ProductCustomer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
      'product_id',
      'name',
      'lastname',
      'city',
      'district',
      'address',
      'email',
      'phone'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

My model's migration.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("product_id");
            $table->string("name");
            $table->string("lastname");
            $table->string("city");
            $table->string("district");
            $table->string("address");
            $table->string("email");
            $table->string("phone");
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

My insertion test passes.

```
public function test_insert()
    {
        $product = Product::factory()->create();
        $pc = ProductCustomer::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $this->faker->name,
        'lastname' => $this->faker->lastName,
        'city' => $this->faker->city,
        'district' => $this->faker->city,
        'address' => $this->faker->address,
        'email' => $this->faker->email,
        'phone' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
    ]);

        $this->assertModelExists($pc);
    }
```

So the mindblowing part is this test can insert the data into the database. But below, there is no exception, no error but no action.

```
private function insertCustomer($request, $productId)
    {
        try {
            return ProductCustomer::create([
                'product_id' => $productId,
                'name' => $request->name,
                'lastname' => $request->lastname,
                'city' => $request->city,
                'district' => $request->state,
                'address' => $request->address,
                'email' => $request->mail,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
            ]);
        } catch (QueryException $e)
        {
            dd($e);
        }
    }

 public function commitPayment(Request $request, $productId) {
        $this->insertCustomer($request,$productId);
        $response = $this->preparePayment($request,$productId)->save();

        return $this->isPaymentSuccess($response);
    }
```

You can see $request and $productId below. There is no problem.

```
    +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#44 ▼
        #parameters: array:9 [▼
          "_token" => "lOI9cI4GQ9OWtciQgAWAQX3b48sw2KqcGmhKqXi2"
          "productId" => "99ef04f9-612f-43f1-a39e-56f94a96edf7"
          "name" => "John"
          "lastname" => "Doe"
          "city" => "Istanbul"
          "state" => "Uskudar"
          "address" => "Test address"
          "mail" => "test@gmail.com"
          "phone" => "+905555454545"
        ]
      }

^ "99ef04f9-612f-43f1-a39e-56f94a96edf7"
```

Edit 2: For testing, I added dd() for Product Customer::created event. It was triggered so it means Product Customer::create() works fine. But in the database, there is no record contrary of the test. Here is the dd($model) results.

```
App\Models\Payment\ProductCustomer {#1534 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "product_customers"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▼
    "product_id" => "42d9e84e-7d4c-49c8-8ddf-2327300a3a64"
    "name" => "John"
    "lastname" => "Doe"
    "city" => "HATAY"
    "district" => "HASSA"
    "address" => "test address"
    "email" => "test@mail.com"
    "phone" => "4445556677"
    "updated_at" => "2022-06-02 15:51:55"
    "created_at" => "2022-06-02 15:51:55"
    "id" => 12
  ]
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:8 [▼
    0 => "product_id"
    1 => "name"
    2 => "lastname"
    3 => "city"
    4 => "district"
    5 => "address"
    6 => "email"
    7 => "phone"
  ]
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Edit 3: Finally I found the problem.  I trailed the non-test case way from route to end. And I noticed I have a `DB:prepareCommit` command at the start. In the end, everything works fine but I have an event that tries to get ProductCustomer which I tried to create but it wasn't committed yet with `DB:commit`. So the event is failing because the record doesn't exist and the database rolling back.

Comment: what is $response result in $this->preparePayment()? does it save?
do every thing reach to insertCustomer() ? (test with dd() )

Comment: Yes, i tested with dd(), it reaches the insertCustomer and runs correctly but doesn't insert the data.

Comment: I see you aren't calling `->save();` anywhere

Comment: @geertjanknapen According to [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts) laravel docs. ->save() function is not mandatory with static create() function.

Comment: just for test : please remove try-catch, use firstorNew, you can also move create() from insertCustomer() to commitPayment.

Comment: @parastoo I tried. no error, no success, no exception.

Comment: is `ProductCustomer` using the correct imported class for the non-test case? Based on the given code and the comments, one guess is that the wrong class is imported. If not, maybe a guard interfering?

Comment: Hold up, are you trying the non-testcase through submitting a form? if so, please make sure you use csrf. `<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" id="token">`

Comment: @PatricNox yes I double-checked the imports, nothing wrong. I don't understand what you mean by guard interfering, but I can say there is no additional middleware or guard function while the non-test case is working. 

Edit : you can see the $request output above. Token exist in request.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. I trailed the non-test case way from route to end. And I noticed I have a `DB:prepareCommit` command at the start. In the end, everything works fine but I have an event that tries to get ProductCustomer which I tried to create but it wasn't committed yet with `DB:commit`. So the event is failing because the record doesn't exist and the database rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch all errors using [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php).
Throwable is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement, including Error and Exception.

```
<?php

try {
// your code
} catch (Throwable $e) {
   echo 'Catch Exception and Error exceptions';
}
```

A popular mistake is when you expect an error of type A but got an error with type B and can't understand why it doesn't fall into the catch block where you expect an error of type A.

Comment: According to your comment:
Edit 2: For testing, I added dd() for Product Customer::created event. 
It was triggered so it means Product Customer::create() works fine.
As I see you added dd() into a catch block and If you see a result It means that ***Product Customer::create()*** doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `DB::commit` and `DB:prepareCommit`, better way how to use transaction:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);

    DB::commit();
    // all good
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}
```

See the [transaction docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database#database-transactions).